# Cropping ROI and non ROI

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, image-classification

I have an image that has one mask (in the attached image there is an blue annotation to show the masked region). I came cross this function to crop the ROI (that is in blue annotation). I want crop non ROI regions as well. Please let me know how to do that. I wrote comments for below code to show how I understood the code. Let me know if I am wrong.

Kidney image with ROI:

[image: Kidney image with ROI]

```py
def ROI_polygons(img, cnts, pad=5):
    def get_ROI_polygons(_img, _cnt, _pad):
        x1,y1,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(np.array(_cnt)) # draw an approximate rectangle around the binary image
        x2,y2 = x1+w+_pad, y1+h+_pad # Add padding for cropped part
        x1, y1 = max(0, x1-_pad), max(0, y1-_pad)
        return _img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
    ROI_crops = [get_ROI_polygons(img, cnt, pad) for cnt in cnts]
return ROI_crops
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: unclear. what do you consider "non-roi" and what do you mean by "crop"

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I want to do 'tiling' for the entire image. Then, I want to extract and save the tiles having a region of interest in blue annotations in one folder and the rest of the tiles in another folder.